# How Can I Apply CSS to an iFrame Using OK_loadit Function?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I am attempting to apply CSS to a document that I'm loading into an iFrame. I am using the OK_loadit function as follows:

```
function OK_loadit(url,layerObjNS, width) { 
 if (document.layers){
         document.layers[layerObjNS].load(url, width);
    } else{
         if (window.frames.length > -1){
             window.frames[layerObjNS].location.href = url;
}
```

The document I am loading into the iFrame is a php Seresnipity blog page.

The blog page's CSS needs to be set to "**background= #000000**", so that it can be viewed from links in the RSS feed with a black background. That's already done.

But when the blog page is rendered in it's iFrame on my website (which is located on the same domain as the blog), it's CSS needs to be set to "**background= transparent**".

Is there any way to modify the OK_loadit script above in such a way that I can reset the background parameter of the page accordingly when it's loaded into the iFrame, or do I need to use a different script altogether?

Either way, I'd really appreciate it if someone here could hook me up with what I need.

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
deleted previous answer
[/edit]

sorry, I re-read your question and realized that the solution is easier than I had thought.

in the url that you're passing to this page just add ?tran to the url string..

so...

"myPage.php?tran"

then in the php page add this...

```
<script>
document.onload = function(){
   if(self.location.query.indexOf("?tran") == 0)
   document.bgColor = "transparent"

}
</script>
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Wow. You lost me there. A little over my head i guess. I don't code in js, so I'm at a loss as to how to "grab a query", parse values, etc. Is there any way you could write it out for me without being a pain? I realize that's why programmers are paid, so if it's asking too much I understand. I really appreciate your above response though, either way. Thanks.

Comment: Wait a minute... I think I figured it out. I need to go "background color=self.location.search" in the target page, right?

My problem is that the target page (index.php) is actually a php page that is "constructed" by the blog app, so all of the parameters that control the CSS of the page are located in a CSS file. So it gets kind of sticky there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: almost... you need to extract the value from the query... I guess if it's the ONLY thing you're passing in, you can just pass in the color and grab the string from the second char and to the end.  As to the PHP, it doesn't matter how the page is generated, you can set the style manually after the page loads, but if the code you're looking at above is over your head, then it'll be tricky to talk you through how to implement it.  No offense, but if *this is too tough, why have you been left to perform this task? This is pretty elementary stuff.

Comment: I edited my answer with more details in the code... let me know if that's any more help

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. Unfortunately, the php page is so complex (it's a serindipity blog) that I doubt that script is going to work... but I'm going to give it a try. The php page uses 2 .tpl template files and several other php and css files to construct the output, so this is not really going to be a straightforward application at all. I've been left to perform this task because i created this monster. ;-) I am the coder & the only person on the planet who knows what I'm doing. There's something to be said 4 going to school 4 programming if you're going 2 build websites, right? hehe

Comment: Yeah, i can tell already that it's not going to work, because the blog calls on a style.css file somewhere in the convoluted mess that makes up the core files of the blog code, and that's going to override anything I add to the index.php page. Additionally, I've attempted to add the code above to the file and it's giving me syntax errors. The <script> tags are breaking the rest of the code on the page. It doesn't like the "document." commands either (if I remove the script tags).

Comment: Perhaps I could assign a variable in php (within index.php) to equal the query string, include some logic which would set that variable to "#000000" if the query<>"transparent", and then set the background color parameter within the style.css to equal the variable. I think that would probably be the ticket. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: James, you're over thinking this. PHP generates a page, let it do that. The code I'm suggesting is going to fire onload, meaning, it will work after all your templates and other good stuff have done their job. So, no matter what your css says, this will overwrite it and set the background to transparent *after the page has finished loading.  So... just add that script as the very last thing the page does (or if you can find the <head> tag in your mess, as the last thing that happens inside that) and you can test it outside the other script by just calling it...

Comment: directly via http://foo.com/mypage.php?transparent  add a line in there to alert(document.bgColor) right after the line where you assign it, to make sure it's being called.